# What is express.static in Express?

Tags: node.js, express

I am new in `Node/Express`. I am trying to build a static website using Express. I have an assets directory and some pages on the root directory of the project. By googling, got some resources there I got a statement like this:

```
app.use('/assets', express.static(__dirname + '/assets'));
```

I know about **`__dirname`** is a current working directory and **`app.use()`** acts as a middleware function, unlike **`app.get()`** and so on. By searching about **`express.static`** got documentation link [Serving static files in Express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

But I am unclear and confused. I hope someone will be able to help me and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`express.static` exposes a directory or a file to a particular URL so it's contents can be **publicly** accessed.

From your example:

```
app.use('/assets', express.static(__dirname + '/assets'));
```

Assuming the `/assets` directory contains 2 images, `foo.jpg` and `bar.jpg` then you can simply access them at:

- http://your-domain.com/assets/foo.jpg
- http://your-domain.com/assets/bar.jpg

There's nothing more to it.

Answer (score 1):

The **app.use(express.static('assets'))** code is used to serve static files such as images, CSS files, and JavaScript files in an Express app. The express.static middleware function is used to expose a directory or a file to a particular URL so its contents can be publicly accessed. In this case, the assets directory is exposed to the /assets URL.

For example, if you have an image file named image.jpg in the assets directory, you can access it via the URL

> http://localhost:3000/assets/image.jpg.

Comment: Hi, your answer is basically the same as the accepted other. While answering, if there is already an accepted answer, be sure to add some interesting/important value. Take  alook at  [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)